# Is it possible to construct modulo classes that cover the integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

> I am trying to construct (or disprove the existence of) some finite
>   set, $S=\left\{(y,k)\mid y,k\in\mathbb{Z},y\ge2\right\}$, where no two
>   $y$ are the same, and every integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ may be written as
>   $x=n\cdot y_i + k_i$, where $(y_i,k_i)\in S$.

In other words, I am wondering if it might be possible to perhaps construct something like:

$$x+k_1\equiv r_1\pmod2$$

$$x+k_2\equiv r_2\pmod3$$

$$x+k_3\equiv r_3\pmod4$$

$$\vdots$$

$$x+k_i\equiv r_i\pmod {i+1}$$

where, for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, there is at least one $0 < j\le i$ where $r_j=0$.

So far I have written a greedy algorithm in python to try and find an example, with no luck. For example, the best case I have found for $i=4$ gives a covering of $\frac{56}{60}=\frac{14}{15}$ of the integers. I have a feeling it is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! What you're asking for, in Wikipedia's terminology, is a [distinct covering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system). Here's a nice example:

$$\{0(\mathrm{mod}\ {2}),\ 0(\mathrm{mod}\ {3}),\ 1(\mathrm{mod}\ {4}),
\ 5(\mathrm{mod}\ {6}),\ 7(\mathrm{mod}\ {12})
\}$$

According to [arXiv:math/0412217v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412217v2), the above was found by Erdős, as well as this one:

$${0(2), 0(3), 0(5), 1(6), 0(7), 1(10), 1(14), 2(15),
2(21), 23(30), 4(35), 5(42), 59(70), 104(105)}$$